# Up e Down votes no Meta funcionam da mesma forma que no SOPT?

Tags: debate, suporte

Acabo de investir alguns minutos na leitura de alguns posts do meta, e upvotei (putz, isso é horrível, quase tanto quanto "me add no orkut" =P) boas perguntas e suas respectivas boas respostas.

Minha questão é: alguém ganha rep por emitir uma boa opinião, da mesma forma que ganha rep por produzir uma boa resposta objetiva?

Ou aqui no Meta os votos tem mais uma conotação de valorizar as questões mais pertinentes para a comunidade no momento, enquanto confirmam as melhores opiniões a respeito de determinado assunto, ou no contexto de um debate?

Answer (score 10):

Boa questão, principalmente para orientar quem ainda não conhece bem a filosofia do meta.

O meta é totalmente diferente. Aqui tem até tag p/ valorizar discussão, o que é "proibido" no site principal. Note que até  perguntas que envolvem um pouco de socialização são toleradas. E perguntas que são votações (poll questions) aqui são muito comuns. Então o votos aqui servem não so para indicar pertinência para a comunidade, mas **AQUI no meta** os votos em respostas e em alguns casos na pergunta também costumam indicar apoio ou contrariedade a algo postado. É comum no meta encontrar posts com votação negativa e isso não é ruim. Na verdade isso não aconteceu ainda porque a maioria ainda não entendeu como funciona aqui.

A votação no site principal deve ser usado para valorizar o que é pertinente e útil para a comunidade (mais nas perguntas) e o que responde mais pertinentemente e corretamente o que o OP/AP perguntou. Lá não se usa o voto para indicar apoio ou discordância, como é feito aqui.

Deu para entender o motivo da atividade exercida aqui não influenciar a reputação do site? Se fosse assim, as pessoas evitariam discussões e colocar posições polêmicas, altamente necessárias, para não perder reputação, um erro que foi cometido no [metão/MSO](http://meta.stackoveflow.com) que foi tornado um site independente com reputação.

Então votem à vontade aqui para expressar sua posição. O voto é melhor que dar respostas ou comentários que não acrescentem nada.

O voto no comentário serve para isso também. Expressar que o comentário é útil e deva se destacar em relação aos demais além de concordar é a função do up no comentário. É melhor que dizer "concordo" ou "+1" ou "obrigado" que o site já indica que não é para fazer.

Na verdade acho que o pessoal deveria votar mais aqui e no principal. Claro que sem votar por votar. Com consciência, votar logo e votar sempre. <sub>(ainda vou achar tempo p/ escrever sobre isso :) )</sub>

Comment: Não seria o caso de ter title's para upvotes diferentes aqui no meta?

Comment: Não vejo vantagem.